# Logging in to apache server using unencrypted password?

Tags: apache

Pretty simple question, I have a local apache server running on my computer to run the phproxy script, and then setup the .htpasswd and .htaccess files to secure it. All went well, except I cannot login using the unencrypted password as I believed you were able to, is something wrong or did I hear wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use digest authentication.

Short guide:
http://www.widexl.com/tutorials/htaccess.html#auth_digest

However it's md5, so it isn't so secure after all (but always better then plaintext).